# separate some selenum scripts by a space character to run them ruby rake

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver, rake

I'm using Ruby Rake to run a Selenium Webdriver script on Ruby Terminal window. So, I have the code in rakefile.rb as below:

```
task :default do
    if ENV['scripts']
       scripts = ENV['scripts'].split(',')
end
```

the code "scripts = ENV['scripts'].split(',')" mean that if I want to run many scripts ex: 'test1.rb' & 'test2.rb', so I have to use a comma(,) between the name of two scripts that I want to run like below:

```
C:\>rake scripts=test1.rb,test2.rb
```

But now I want to change the code so that I can use a space character b/w scripts instead of (,)

```
C:\>rake scripts=test1.rb test2.rb
```

How can I do it, please help, Thanks much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rake will treat the second script as call to a task, so you need to group the arguments by enclosing them in quotes:

```
$ rake scripts='test1.rb test2.rb'
```

Then, you can call `split` without arguments in your Rake task:

```
task :default do
  if ENV['scripts']
    scripts = ENV['scripts'].split
    p scripts
  end
end
```

This will produce:

```
$ rake scripts='test1.rb test2.rb'
["test1.rb", "test2.rb"]
```

Another option is to fiddle with the command line arguments yourself, and then dynamically defining tasks with the name of the command line arguments, so rake won't complain about missing tasks. I've extracted this into a method called `with_args` here:

```
# expose command line arguments
def with_args &block
  args = ARGV.dup
  args.shift
  block.call(args)
  args.each{|arg| task(arg.to_sym) }
end
```

You can use it like this:

```
task :default => [:scripts]

task :scripts do
  with_args do |files|
    p files
  end
end
```

And then invoke the rake task this way:

```
$ rake scripts test1.rb test2.rb
["test1.rb", "test2.rb"]
```

The initial idea came from [this blog post](http://itshouldbeuseful.wordpress.com/2011/11/07/passing-parameters-to-a-rake-task/).

Comment: Thanks so much for your great and detail answer.